# H323 Video with Freeswitch mod_h323 possible?

Tags: sip, freeswitch, h.323

I am investigating if its possible to use mod_h323 with freeswitch for video. I need a layer to convert my sip video phone into a H323 only device. I was hoping to use freeswitch or any other provider to sit in the middle and translate the video and signalling between the two devices.

I am having trouble compiling the mod_h323 library and before I pay for support I was wondering if anyone had tried this and can confirm it works or doesn't.

Thanks,
Jacob